# Android inserting an image as an inputstream possible?

Tags: java, android, inputstream, java-io, android-image

My task for this class is to insert an image of a can (or cans) and replace it with the red tiles that are in the Android game. I understand the code so far, yet I have an issue with `inputstream`. How can I use `inputstream` to insert a picture of a can?

```
private Target chooseTarget(int x, int y, int targetNumber) {
    int targetScores [] = {1, 2, 4};    // TODO
    double targetProps [] = {0.6, 0.8}; // TODO
    int targetIndex;

    // zufällige Auswahl des Targets nach Wahrscheinlichkeiten in targetProps
    if(targetNumber==0) { // Also wenn targert == 0
        double dice = random.nextDouble(); // dice ist eine züfallige zahl
        targetIndex = targetProps.length; // targetIndex hat die länge von targetProps
        while (targetIndex > 0 && dice < targetProps[targetIndex-1]) // solange targetIndex > 0 && dice < als Inhalt targetprops Array
            targetIndex--; // Ziehe 1 ab von targetIndex
        targetNumber = targetIndex+1; // targetNumber =
    } else  // explizite Wahl der Nummer des Targets
    {
        if(targetNumber<1 || targetNumber>targetScores.length)    // explizit ausgewähltes Target
            targetNumber = 1;
        targetIndex=targetNumber-1;
    }

    return new Target(x, y, null, targetScores[targetIndex]);   // TODO
}
```

Here are the constructors:

```
 public Target(int x, int y, InputStream is) {
    super(x, y, is);

    //tilePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BF1111")); /// Farbe Rot
}

public Target(int x, int y, InputStream is, int score) {
    this(x, y, is);
    this.score = score;
}
```

I commented out the red tile part. I am supposed to change only the call of the constructor.

Comment: What kind of object is `Target`

Comment: It's an ArrayList.